# Call Mixin global method from Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a mixin like this with a request method to call axios and handle errors, etc.:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios';
    
Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        request(url, datas) {

        //Call axios and return premise
        [...]
    }
});
```

I have a store like this :

```js
const actions = {
    selectEmployees: (store, keywords) => {
        this.request(`/users/list/search{/keywords}`).then(e => {
            store.commit('SELECT_EMPLOYEES', e.data)
        });
    }
}
    
let store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: state,
    mutations: mutations,
    getters: getters,
    actions: actions
})
```

I would like to use request to call axios but I have this error:

> Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of
> undefined" TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined

Comment: could you provide the code of main.js?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mixins, as stated from the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html), are used for components. Vuex is not a component itself. As I can see you're using the new import/export ways of working, just make your mixing a simple functions that are exported. Then elsewhere either attach them to Vue as mixin, or use it externally in the store. Something along the lines (semi code):

```js
// mixin.js
export default function request() {}

// main.js
Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        request: mixin.request // will provide this.request in each component
    }
}

// store.js
mixin.request() // will fire the method
```

Comment: And how would you obtain the mixin within store.js? 

Comment: As `import mixin from './wherever/the/file/is';`

Comment: And if I want to call the Global Mixin form a vue instance? `vm = new Vue()` `vm.mixinMethod()`??

Comment: IN THIS CASE if you `import mixin from './wherever/the/file/is';` then you can't do `mixin.request()` as suggested above, rather you would call it as `mixin()` to fire the function.

Comment: You named `main.js` the file where the mixin is instantiated, and `mixin.js` the file where are the shared functions. It should be inverse? It's not very clear...

Comment: Well `mixin.js` is the file where the mixin is **defined**, while `main.js` is the place where the mixin is **used**. It makes sense to name the files based on what is the main idea of the code inside, right?

Answer (score 10):

Since the request method is in the mixin's methods obj

```
// store.js 
import mixin from './mixin'

// access mixin method
mixin.methods.request()
```

Comment: Not sure about best practice or whatnot but this worked like a charm

Comment: This defeats the purpose of mixins.

Comment: Way to access methods is perfectly working fine for me also, but the $data variable is not accessible of mixin.js from store.js. could you please help me here?

Comment: @Emobe Can you elaborate on why this defeats the purpose of mixins and offer a solution that does not?

Comment: @Michael Mixins are to be used within a component's `mixin` property. This is just essentially a helper/utility.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
//GlobalMixin.js
const Mixin = {
  methods: {
    _secureHTML(str) {
      return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
    }
  }
}

export { Mixin } //use: import { Mixin } from 'GlobalMixin.js'

// - export it as a Vue Plugin
export default {
  install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.mixin(Mixin)
  }
}
```